# Python: Scrape Data from Web after Inputing Info

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing, lxml, lxml.html

Could anyone help me revise this Python program to correctly submit information to the "Date Range" query, and then extract the "Close" return data. I am scraping data from the following url:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EGSPC+Historical+Prices
```

And this is my current code, which returns "[ ]".

```
from lxml import html
import requests


def historic_quotes(symbol, stMonth, stDate, stYear, enMonth, enDate, enYear):
    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%s+Historical+Prices' % (symbol)

    form_data = {
        'a': stMonth,  #00 is January, 01 is Feb., etc.
        'b': stDate,
        'c': stYear,
        'd': enMonth,  #00 is January, 01 is Feb., etc.
        'e': enDate,
        'f': enYear,
        'submit': 'submit',
    }
response = requests.post(url, data=form_data)

tree = html.document_fromstring(response.content)
p = tree.xpath('//*[@id="yfncsumtab"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/text()')
print p

historic_quotes('baba',00,11,2010,00,11,2012)
```

I am an overall Python novice, and greatly appreciate any and all help.  Thanks for reading!

Also, I realize now the html source may be of help, but it is huge - so here's an XPATH to it:

```
//*[@id="daterange"]/table
```

Expected output is a list of the "Close" Values from the different dates.  As previously stated, current output is just "[ ]".  I believe something may been incorrect in the form_data, perhaps the "submit".

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you can give an example of precisely what you want (as in, the exact output you expect) and some indication of where you think you might be going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Adding now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue was that you needed to make a `GET` request, not a `POST`.

Plus, @Paul Lo is right about the date ranges. For the sake of example, I'm querying from 2010 to 2015.

Also, you have to pass query parameters as strings. `00` evaluated to `0`, `requests` converted int 0 to a `"0"` string. As a result, instead of `00` for a month, you had `0` sent as a parameter value.

Here is a fixed version with a modified part that gets the amounts:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

def historic_quotes(symbol, stMonth, stDate, stYear, enMonth, enDate, enYear):
    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%s+Historical+Prices' % symbol

    params = {
        'a': stMonth,
        'b': stDate,
        'c': stYear,
        'd': enMonth,
        'e': enDate,
        'f': enYear,
        'submit': 'submit',
    }
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)

    tree = html.document_fromstring(response.content)
    for amount in tree.xpath('//table[@class="yfnc_datamodoutline1"]//tr[td[@class="yfnc_tabledata1"]]//td[5]/text()'):
        print amount

historic_quotes('baba', '00', '11', '2010', '00', '11', '2015')
```

Prints:

```
105.95
105.95
105.52
108.77
110.65
109.25
109.02
105.77
104.70
105.11
104.97
103.88
107.48
105.07
107.90
...
90.57
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that Alibaba (BABA) has data during 2010/1/11 to 2012/1/11 since it just IPO recently.
You might need to check the raw data in `response.content` first, and try change the range ex: `historic_quotes('baba',00,11,2014,00,11,2015)`

Comment: Whoops, was previously searching for GSPC.  Forgot to change the query for Alibaba.  Thanks for pointing that one out.